# data not inserting in mysql db using jsp - shows empty page on running process.jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am trying to insert data into the MySQL database with follow .jsp script in netbeans using tomcat server but not working, not giving any error only shows blank page when run process.jsp

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="process.jsp">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="first_name">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="last_name">
<br>
City name:<br>
<input type="text" name="city_name">
<br>
Email Id:<br>
<input type="email" name="email">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

process.jsp code :

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%>

<%
String first_name=request.getParameter("first_name");
String last_name=request.getParameter("last_name");
String city_name=request.getParameter("city_name");
String email=request.getParameter("email");

try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jform", "root", "");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();

int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into users(first_name,last_name,city_name,email)values('"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+city_name+"','"+email+"')");
out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.print(e);
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: **WARNING**: When composing SQL queries it’s important to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/java) any and all user-data to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your code is fine. You may be getting error in your netbeans / tomcat console. For example if in the mysql table you have a column for unique key like "id" make sure that is set as autoincrement. Also make sure you have mysql-connector-java jar file in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks Paul it was the error with mysql-connector-java jar file i have resolved it by:1)Go to Properties of  project

2)Go to Libraries

3)Add Library

4)Select MySQL JDBC Driver